# Uber estimates/time by product_id responding with multiple product times?

Tags: time, uber-api

I am requesting Product times by product_id and I am getting the full list of all product times versus just getting a single response.

```
var productID = "37a94557-682f-4562-ba62-2448f80d3ddd" ;
    $http({
      url: "https://api.uber.com/v1/estimates/time" ,
      headers: {
          Authorization: "Token " + uberServerToken
        },
      params: {
          start_latitude: setLat,
          start_longitude: setLon,
          product_id: productID
        }
      }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            uberTimes = data["times"] ;
            uberTime = Math.round(uberTimes[0].estimate / 60) ;
}) ;
```

Currently, the response I am getting is:

```
times: [{localized_display_name:uberX, estimate:455, display_name:uberX,…},…]     
   0: {localized_display_name:uberX, estimate:455, display_name:uberX,…}
     display_name: "uberX" 
     estimate: 455 
     localized_display_name: "uberX" 
     product_id: "37a94557-682f-4562-ba62-2448f80d3ddd" 

   1: {localized_display_name:uberXL, estimate:455, display_name:uberXL,…}
     display_name: "uberXL" 
     estimate: 455 
     localized_display_name: "uberXL" 
     product_id: "aa0109f3-15db-45ca-b0cc-5019e8557792"
```

1: I would assume I would only get a single product time info because I used the optional "product_id", why am I getting multiple product times?

2: As well, assuming I can just get the single product time would I still access it the same way: "uberTimes[0].estimate"  ???

Answer (score 1):

The `product_id` optional parameter does not filter the results correctly. This is an known bug with the Uber API. In order to retrieve the correct `estimate`, you should process the JSON response and match by `product_id`, e.g.:

```
var myEstimate; 
for result in results {
    if result["product_id"] == product_id {
        myEstimate = result["estimate"];
    }
}
```

You cannot just index by 0 (`uberTimes[0].estimate` in your example), because the response does not guarantee order of results.